# Не работает адаптив

Tags: media-queries

Помогите, почему не работает адаптив на сайте когда заходишь с телефона? Смотрю в режиме адаптива в браузере - всё нормально, захожу с телефона - всё ломается.
http://myasotut23.ru/

Comment: Код добавьте в вопрос(неработающий), а не ссылку на сайт.

Comment: На самом деле, не так просто написать кастомный адаптив. Лучше всего , для базы, использовать FlexBox, Bootstrap или CSSGrid. Тогда проблем с адаптивностью будет намного меньше

Comment: @Klimenkomud, да там, по-моему, весь файл с media не работает. Хоть я и захожу на сайт с мобильной версии - и всё хорошо

Comment: @RomanKozin я делал на флексах

Comment: @RomanKozin Зашёл с одного телефона - не работает адаптив но работает js(Слайдер, яндекс карта), зашёл с другого - адаптив заработал, но js почему-то уже не работает.(Js разрешён в настройках)

Comment: @RomanKozin С яндекс браузера на телефоне всё работает, и адаптив и js

Answer (score 0):

во всех медиа запросах вместо media only screen and (max-widht: Npx), прописал просто media (max-widht: Npx) и всё стало работать нормально.